# RewriteRule Pattern negation in .htaccess results in too many redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What RewriteRule should be used in the `.htaccess` in `/mydir/` to HTTP 302 redirect every request to `http://www.example.com/mydir/output`?

**Current content of `.htaccess` in `/mydir/`:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase "/mydir/"
RewriteRule !"^output$" "output" [R]
```

**Input URLs:**

`http://www.example.com/mydir/input1`,

`http://www.example.com/mydir/input2`,

`http://www.example.com/mydir/input3`

**Expected output:**

`http://www.example.com/mydir/output`,

`http://www.example.com/mydir/output`,

`http://www.example.com/mydir/output`

**Real output:**

`ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`,

`ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`,

`ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase "/mydir/"
RewriteRule "^output$" "-" [L]
RewriteRule ".*" "output" [R]
# Further rules are not processed.
```

**I don't know why does the negation not work**, but the original RewriteRule can be replaced by these 2 above. This way the first RewriteRule stops the whole rewriting process if the URL is already the expected output (see the [dash](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) Substitution and the [L flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l)), to avoid a redirect loop. Otherwise everything is rewritten to the expected output URL by the second RewriteRule. If stopping the whole rewriting process should be avoided, it is possible to skip only the unconditional (second) RewriteRule, so every further rule is processed. To achieve this, use the [S flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_s) as below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase "/mydir/"
RewriteRule "^output$" "-" [S=1]
RewriteRule ".*" "output" [R]
# Further rules are processed as well.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an `L` flag on your rule, but it's too broad; it should only match when that was the actual URL sent to the server. I doubt the final destination of that request is an extensionless file named `output` but that is what your rule's insisting on. Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mydir/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^\S++\s++/mydir/output\s
RewriteRule ^ output [NS,R,L]
# rules after this should now be processed
```

Answer (score -1):

You are checking if your URL is not starting with `output`, and it's always the case. Change the rule to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^/mydir/output$ /mydir/output [R]
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunatelly it doesn't work. Now the output is still `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`. Maybe because of this, but I'm not sure: `The directory path where the rule is defined is stripped from the currently mapped filesystem path before comparison (up to and including a trailing slash). The net result of this per-directory prefix stripping is that rules in this context only match against the portion of the currently mapped filesystem path "below" where the rule is defined.` Source: [What is matched?](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#what_is_matched)

Comment: If the Pattern is `"^output$"` (without `!`), the following URL is matched as expected: `http://www.example.com/mydir/output`. And nothing else matches it, as expected. So when the same pattern is negated, I guess it should **not** match the mentioned URL, but **match** everything else. But it seems like it matches everything, because the rewrite loop (?) suggests the mentioned URL is matched as well.

Comment: You are right. Doubled-checked. Answer updated, you can check again :)

Comment: A note from the down-voter will be nice, as I checked it and it works perfectly.